# How to filter jetty logs by LOG_LEVEL of maven project?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jetty, war

I have problems with logging in jetty. I write logs in file. In resulting log's file a logging level for application is info, but I set set it like WARN. I have idea that jetty write logs from application without filtering, is it so?

1. I use maven and I've packaged my application with command

   ```
   sudo mvn package
   ```
2. set up logging for jetty:

   ```
   {jetty.base}/modules$ sudo curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetty-project/logging-modules/master/log4j-1.2/logging.mod

   {jetty.base}$ sudo java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar --add-to-start=logging
   ```
3. File {jetty.base}/resources/jetty-logging.properties

   ```
   org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
   org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("org.eclipse.jetty").setLevel(Level.WARN);
   org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=WARN
   ```
4. File {jetty.base}/resources/log4j.properties

   ```
   log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file
   log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
   log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
   ```
5. File {jetty.base}/etc/jetty-logging.xml

   ```
   <New id="ServerLog" class="java.io.PrintStream">
     <Arg>
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">
         <Arg><Property name="jetty.logs" default="/mnt/logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.stderrout.log</Arg>
         <Arg type="boolean">false</Arg>
         <Arg type="int">90</Arg>
         <Arg><Call class="java.util.TimeZone" name="getTimeZone"><Arg>GMT</Arg></Call></Arg>
         <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
       </New>
     </Arg>
   </New>

   <Get name="rootLogger">
     <Call name="info"><Arg>Redirecting stderr/stdout to file <Ref refid="ServerLogName"/></Arg></Call>
   </Get>
   <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setErr"><Arg><Ref refid="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>
   <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setOut"><Arg><Ref refid="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>
   ```
6. In logs file I see logging with level Info and debug

   ```
   07:13:10.072 [main] INFO 
   07:14:04.216 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager ...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the `etc/jetty-logging.xml`, your setup isn't using it (you downloaded a custom `modules/logging.mod` that does not reference it)

> You can see what your configuration is using by running `start.jar --list-config`

That XML only exists to support the built-in `StdErrLog` implementation that only writes to `System.err` (aka STDERR).  The `etc/jetty-logging.xml` just takes STDERR and STDOUT and writes it to disk.

Since you are using `log4j`, that entire redirect step is not needed (and would conflict with normal log4j console appender behavior if it were used).

Your `${jetty.base}/resources/jetty-logging.properties` should only be:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
```

It should contain no other lines.

The file `${jetty.base}/resources/log4j.properties` is where you configure your initial named logger levels, and all of the initial appenders you want to use.

You currently have the initial level for set to WARN.

When your server starts up, any piece of code you have can (at runtime) decide to change the level of a specific named logger, and even add/remove appenders at runtime (this is more common then you might expect)

Since you don't have a `Threshold` declared for your appender, it will take all levels seen and append them.

If you don't want to see that DEBUG in your appender, just add the following line to your `${jetty.base}/resources/log4j.properties`

```
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=WARN
```

But you might still want to know what is setting that named logger level outside of the properties file. (check your code)